# When I pressing polish letter such as: ó, ł, ą, ż Script moves 3 spaces, when should move only 1 space

Tags: javascript, crossword

When I pressing polish letter such as: ó, ł, ą, ż  Script moves 3 spaces, when should move only 1 space.
At this page you can try this script: http://daniel.jajuwa.pl/krzyzowka/index.html
I found the code on the internet, that's why I'm writing here because here is the best chance for a reply;)
Thanks for help :D

```js
(function($){
    $.fn.crossword = function(entryData) {
        
            var puzz = {}; 
            puzz.data = entryData;
            

            this.after('<div id="puzzle-clues"><h2>Poziomo</h2><ol id="across"></ol><h2>Pionowo</h2><ol id="down"></ol></div>');
            
            // initialize some variables
            var tbl = ['<table id="puzzle">'],
                count = 12,
                counter = 0,
                puzzEl = this,
                clues = $('#puzzle-clues'),
                clueLiEls,
                coords,
                entryCount = puzz.data.length,
                entries = [], 
                rows = [],
                cols = [],
                solved = [],
                tabindex,
                $actives,
                activePosition = 0,
                activeClueIndex = 0,
                currOri,
                targetInput,
                mode = 'interacting',
                solvedToggle = false,
                z = 0;

            var puzInit = {
                
                init: function() {
                    currOri = 'across';
                    
                    puzz.data.sort(function(a,b) {
                        return a.position - b.position;
                    });

                    puzzEl.delegate('input', 'keyup', function(e){
                        mode = 'interacting';
                        
                        switch(e.which) {
                            case 39:
                            case 37:
                                currOri = 'across';
                                break;
                            case 38:
                            case 40:
                                currOri = 'down';
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        
                        if ( e.keyCode === 9) {
                            return false;
                        } else if (
                            e.keyCode === 37 ||
                            e.keyCode === 38 ||
                            e.keyCode === 39 ||
                            e.keyCode === 40 ||
                            e.keyCode === 8 ||
                            e.keyCode === 46 ) {            
                                                

                            
                            if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46) {
                                currOri === 'across' ? nav.nextPrevNav(e, 37) : nav.nextPrevNav(e, 38); 
                            } else {
                                nav.nextPrevNav(e);
                            }
                            
                            e.preventDefault();
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            
                            console.log('input keyup: '+solvedToggle);
                            
                            puzInit.checkAnswer(e);

                        }

                        e.preventDefault();
                        return false;                   
                    });
            
                    // tab navigation handler setup
                    puzzEl.delegate('input', 'keydown', function(e) {

                        if ( e.keyCode === 9) {
                            
                            mode = "setting ui";
                            if (solvedToggle) solvedToggle = false;

                            //puzInit.checkAnswer(e)
                            nav.updateByEntry(e);
                            
                        } else {
                            return true;
                        }
                                                
                        e.preventDefault();
                                    
                    });
                    
                    // tab navigation handler setup
                    puzzEl.delegate('input', 'click', function(e) {
                        mode = "setting ui";
                        if (solvedToggle) solvedToggle = false;

                        console.log('input click: '+solvedToggle);
                    
                        nav.updateByEntry(e);
                        e.preventDefault();
                                    
                    });
                    
                    
                    // click/tab clues 'navigation' handler setup
                    clues.delegate('li', 'click', function(e) {
                        mode = 'setting ui';
                        
                        if (!e.keyCode) {
                            nav.updateByNav(e);
                        } 
                        e.preventDefault(); 
                    });
                    
                    
                    // highlight the letter in selected 'light' - better ux than making user highlight letter with second action
                    puzzEl.delegate('#puzzle', 'click', function(e) {
                        $(e.target).focus();
                        $(e.target).select();
                    });
                    
                    // DELETE FOR BG
                    puzInit.calcCoords();
                    
                    // Puzzle clues added to DOM in calcCoords(), so now immediately put mouse focus on first clue
                    clueLiEls = $('#puzzle-clues li');
                    //$('#' + currOri + ' li' ).eq(0).addClass('clues-active').focus();
                    //REMOVED TO STOP FIRST CLUE FROM LOADING ^^^^^
                
                    // DELETE FOR BG
                    puzInit.buildTable();
                    puzInit.buildEntries();
                                        
                },


            }; // end puzInit object
            

            var nav = {
                
                nextPrevNav: function(e, override) {

                    var len = $actives.length,
                        struck = override ? override : e.which,
                        el = $(e.target),
                        p = el.parent(),
                        ps = el.parents(),
                        selector;
                
                    util.getActivePositionFromClassGroup(el);
                    util.highlightEntry();
                    util.highlightClue();
                    
                    $('.current').removeClass('current');
                    
                    selector = '.position-' + activePosition + ' input';
                    
                    //console.log('nextPrevNav activePosition & struck: '+ activePosition + ' '+struck);
                        
                    // move input focus/select to 'next' input
                    switch(struck) {
                        case 39:
                            p
                                .next()
                                .find('input')
                                .addClass('current')
                                .select();

                            break;
                        
                        case 37:
                            p
                                .prev()
                                .find('input')
                                .addClass('current')
                                .select();

                            break;

                        case 40:
                            ps
                                .next('tr')
                                .find(selector)
                                .addClass('current')
                                .select();

                            break;

                        case 38:
                            ps
                                .prev('tr')
                                .find(selector)
                                .addClass('current')
                                .select();

                            break;

                        default:
                        break;
                    }
                                                            
                },
    
                updateByNav: function(e) {
                    var target;
                    
                    $('.clues-active').removeClass('clues-active');
                    $('.active').removeClass('active');
                    $('.current').removeClass('current');
                    currIndex = 0;

                    target = e.target;
                    activePosition = $(e.target).data('position');
                    
                    util.highlightEntry();
                    util.highlightClue();
                                        
                    $('.active').eq(0).focus();
                    $('.active').eq(0).select();
                    $('.active').eq(0).addClass('current');
                    
                    // store orientation for 'smart' auto-selecting next input
                    currOri = $('.clues-active').parent('ol').prop('id');
                                        
                    activeClueIndex = $(clueLiEls).index(e.target);
                    //console.log('updateByNav() activeClueIndex: '+activeClueIndex);
                    
                },
            
                // Sets activePosition var and adds active class to current entry
                updateByEntry: function(e, next) {
                    var classes, next, clue, e1Ori, e2Ori, e1Cell, e2Cell;
                    
                    if(e.keyCode === 9 || next){
                        // handle tabbing through problems, which keys off clues and requires different handling        
                        activeClueIndex = activeClueIndex === clueLiEls.length-1 ? 0 : ++activeClueIndex;
                    
                        $('.clues-active').removeClass('.clues-active');
                                                
                        next = $(clueLiEls[activeClueIndex]);
                        currOri = next.parent().prop('id');
                        activePosition = $(next).data('position');
                                                
                        // skips over already-solved problems
                        util.getSkips(activeClueIndex);
                        activePosition = $(clueLiEls[activeClueIndex]).data('position');
                        
                                                                                                
                    } else {
                        activeClueIndex = activeClueIndex === clueLiEls.length-1 ? 0 : ++activeClueIndex;
                    
                        util.getActivePositionFromClassGroup(e.target);
                        
                        clue = $(clueLiEls + '[data-position=' + activePosition + ']');
                        activeClueIndex = $(clueLiEls).index(clue);
                        
                        currOri = clue.parent().prop('id');
                        
                    }
                        
                        util.highlightEntry();
                        util.highlightClue();
                        
                        //$actives.eq(0).addClass('current');   
                        //console.log('nav.updateByEntry() reports activePosition as: '+activePosition);    
                }
                
            }; // end nav object

            
            var util = {
                highlightEntry: function() {
                    // this routine needs to be smarter because it doesn't need to fire every time, only
                    // when activePosition changes
                    $actives = $('.active');
                    $actives.removeClass('active');
                    $actives = $('.position-' + activePosition + ' input').addClass('active');
                    $actives.eq(0).focus();
                    $actives.eq(0).select();
                },
                
                highlightClue: function() {
                    var clue;               
                    $('.clues-active').removeClass('clues-active');
                    $(clueLiEls + '[data-position=' + activePosition + ']').addClass('clues-active');
                    
                    if (mode === 'interacting') {
                        clue = $(clueLiEls + '[data-position=' + activePosition + ']');
                        activeClueIndex = $(clueLiEls).index(clue);
                    };
                },
                

                getActivePositionFromClassGroup: function(el){

                        classes = util.getClasses($(el).parent(), 'position');

                        if(classes.length > 1){
                            // get orientation for each reported position
                            e1Ori = $(clueLiEls + '[data-position=' + classes[0].split('-')[1] + ']').parent().prop('id');
                            e2Ori = $(clueLiEls + '[data-position=' + classes[1].split('-')[1] + ']').parent().prop('id');

                            // test if clicked input is first in series. If so, and it intersects with
                            // entry of opposite orientation, switch to select this one instead
                            e1Cell = $('.position-' + classes[0].split('-')[1] + ' input').index(el);
                            e2Cell = $('.position-' + classes[1].split('-')[1] + ' input').index(el);

                            if(mode === "setting ui"){
                                currOri = e1Cell === 0 ? e1Ori : e2Ori; // change orientation if cell clicked was first in a entry of opposite direction
                            }

                            if(e1Ori === currOri){
                                activePosition = classes[0].split('-')[1];      
                            } else if(e2Ori === currOri){
                                activePosition = classes[1].split('-')[1];
                            }
                        } else {
                            activePosition = classes[0].split('-')[1];                      
                        }
                        
                        console.log('getActivePositionFromClassGroup activePosition: '+activePosition);
                        
                },
                
                checkSolved: function(valToCheck) {
                    for (var i=0, s=solved.length; i < s; i++) {
                        if(valToCheck === solved[i]){
                            return true;
                        }

                    }
                },
                
                getSkips: function(position) {
                    if ($(clueLiEls[position]).hasClass('clue-done')){
                        activeClueIndex = position === clueLiEls.length-1 ? 0 : ++activeClueIndex;
                        util.getSkips(activeClueIndex);                     
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                
            }; // end util object

                
            puzInit.init();
    
                            
    }
    
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: That's a lot of code you're asking volunteers to comb through looking for why it's misbehaving. Please take some time to debug the code and find out where the code is advancing, and how it is determining how many to advance. Do note the code is old; it was built on an early version of jQuery (prior to 3 anyway).

Comment: No, the best chance for a reply is to write the author, Jesse Weisbeck. Maybe even [just open an issue on Github](https://github.com/jweisbeck/Crossword/issues)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is simple don't use it